# import matlab.engine leads to RESTART: Shell

Tags: python, matlab, shell

I tried to use the MATLAB Engine within Python on OS X. I installed it via:

```
cd "matlabroot/extern/engines/python"
python setup.py install
```

When I run my code now:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
tf = eng.isprime(37)
print tf
```

I get

```
=============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================
>>>
```

Can anyone tell me what I can do to make it running?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Thanks for thinking about my problem! I am using Python 2.7.11 and Matlab R2015b.